# Equivalent of ServiceBase.OnCustomCommand in BackgroundService in .NET Core / .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, windows-services, .net-5

I have created a Windows Service in .NET Core (also in .NET 5) using a `BackgroundService` worker, running it as a Windows Service using the `IHostBuilder.UseWindowsService()` call.

My question is, how do I capture Windows Service commands such as

`sc.exe control <my service name> 200`

As far as I have been able to tell, there is no equivalent to the old `ServiceBase.OnCustomCommand` that I can capture in this new way of building Windows Services.

Any help on how to capture those commands would be appreciated.  Even if the answer is just *"go back to using ServiceBase for your Windows Service"*.

Thanks!

Comment: The two classes aren't equivalent at all. `BackgroundService` is *not* used to create Windows Services.  It';s meant to run long-running operations in web apps, console apps etc.

Comment: A Windows service is a specific way of hosting an executable. You create a Windows service when you use the Worker project template, add the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices package and use `.UseWindowsService()` [as shown here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). For Linux, you'd use the same package and `UseSystemd()`

Comment: If you want to send commands to your service, you can [create an HTTP endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#routing-basics) that listens for requests. This would allow you to make far more complex requests than the simple values used by Windows services. Your code would be cross-platform too

Comment: So I get all of that (`BackgroundService` is not related to a Windows Service at all)- I am wondering, however, if there is a way to capture the commands that are sent to the Windows Service host which contains the `BackgroundService`.  It seems to me that there should be a way to capture those through the `IHost` interface, if full support for Windows Services is intended.  There are obviously hooks in there for the `Start` and `Stop` commands, so it seems like there must be a way to capture any other service commands sent to the host (even if it's not exposed through the 'IHost'.

Comment: Also, setting up an HTTP endpoint is obviously an option for new stuff, but when working with legacy systems that only interact with the Service Controller, it becomes an issue.

Comment: I repeat, BackgroundService has nothing to do with Windows Services. Hosting as a Windows Service is provided by the [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/WindowsServices/src/WindowsServiceLifetime.cs) package and specifically the [WindowsServiceLifetime](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/WindowsServices/src/WindowsServiceLifetime.cs) class which *doesn't* execute anything. It only controls starting/stopping the host. There's no reference to BackgroundService or IHostedService there

Comment: You could create your own `Lifetime` class that inherits from `WindowsServiceLifetime` and implement `OnCustomCommand` but you'd still need a way to communicate with other classes in your program, perhaps by adding a constructor dependency to the class/interface you want to call. The [UseWindowsService](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/WindowsServices/src/WindowsServiceLifetimeHostBuilderExtensions.cs) method registers `WindowsServiceLifetime` as a singleton. You'll have to write your own `Use...` method to use your derived lifetime class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone still looking for an answer. See [this answer on github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/50021#issuecomment-547503684) for a solution

It is basically about to register a custom `IHostLifetime` implementation:

```cs
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        if (WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService())
            services.AddSingleton<IHostLifetime, CustomService>();
    })
```

The actual implementation may be inheriting from `WindowsServiceLifetime` where you can override the `OnCustomCommand` method:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Will handle custom service commands
/// </summary>
/// <param name="command">The command message sent to the service.</param>
protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Received custom service control command: {0}", command);
    switch (command)
    {
        case PreShutdownCommandCode:
            // Handle your custom command code
            break;
        default:
            base.OnCustomCommand(command);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I ended up going a different direction, but this will be useful if I ever have to deal with this again!

Comment: @Sebastian - I'm not sure what's the CustomService is. 
I did like your code, but get error https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/roslyn.query?appId=roslyn&k=k(CS0311)

Comment: @R.Phani Sorry, this is not clear from example code. In this case, the CustomService is inherited from [ServiceBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase). This also includes `WebHostService` and `WindowsServiceLifetime`.